# Increment within a MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql

I have data that looks like this:

```
id        start_time               sub_id   
 6    2015-01-03 19:00:00             3    
 5    2015-01-03 18:00:00             3         
 4    2015-01-03 17:00:00             3    
 3    2015-01-02 15:08:00             2   
 2    2015-01-01 14:08:00             2    
 1    2015-01-01 22:00:00             1
```

And I'd like to use a query to transform the data as follows:

```
id        start_time               sub_id   stage 
 6    2015-01-03 19:00:00             3       3
 5    2015-01-03 18:00:00             3       2 
 4    2015-01-03 17:00:00             3       1
 3    2015-01-02 15:08:00             2       2
 2    2015-01-01 14:08:00             2       1
 1    2015-01-01 22:00:00             1       1
```

Without the ability to change the table itself, just to query to it.

I'm trying to create an additional column "stage" within my query results that counts the appearance of the sub_id in the table, starting over at each new sub_id.

I've seen some suggestions to use cursors or other methods, but those were to count rows for the entire table, rather than restarting the count when a row's value changes from the one before it.

How should I go about doing this? Is it something that's possible in native MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6672f/12)

```
SET @row_number:=0; 
SET @sub_id:= 0; 

SELECT id, 
       start_time, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @sub_id = sub_id THEN @row_number := @row_number + 1 
         ELSE @row_number := 1 
       end AS ROWNO, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @sub_id <> sub_id THEN @sub_id := sub_id 
         ELSE @sub_id 
       end 
FROM   dates 
ORDER  BY sub_id DESC, 
          rowno DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with variables:

```
select d.*,
       (@rn := if(@s = sub_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@s := sub_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as stage
from data d cross join
     (select @s := 0, @rn := 0) params
order by sub_id, id desc;
```

It is very important to assign the variables and use them in only a single expression, which is why this version has a nested `if()`.  MySQL documentation is quite clear that you should avoid assigning a variable in one expression and using it in another.